# How to find Hwnd of SaveAs button of IE11 dialog

Tags: c#, sendmessage, user32

I am usuing WatIn i make login.....download click,after this i have download function that works fine but only when window is not loked.Sow i want to change .Invoke() to User32 SendMessage() because it can work even if windows is loked but for this i need Hwnd of saveAs button or if any one know another way to click on it i wll be very happy.

My code (only the function that press button) dont see reson to put all code

```
          public static void ClickSaveAs(AutomationElement mainWindow, AutomationElementCollection dialogElements, string filename)
                {
                    foreach (AutomationElement element in dialogElements)
                    {

                        if (element.Current.Name.Equals("Save"))
                        {
  AutomationElementCollection dialogSubElements = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.ControlViewCondition);
                            InvokePattern clickPatternForSaveDropdown = (InvokePattern)dialogSubElements[0].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(10000));



    //here i trying to to find Hwnd of save button 
    //But i think there is way to take Hwnd  from  clickPatternForSaveDropdown                      
     IntPtr BtnTest = FindWindowEx(BtnFatherTest2, 0, "Button", "");
     IntPtr BtnTest2 = FindWindowEx(BtnFatherTest, 0, "", "Save");

     int intRes1 = SendMessage(BtnTest2 , WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     intRes1 = SendMessage(BtnTest2 , WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 1);


     clickPatternForSaveDropdown.Invoke();//here the Invoke that click on button

        }
    }

    }
```